# Cannot connect with public/private key between different version of openSSH

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, centos, openssh

I generate public/private keys to connecto to server with ssh without write password every time. I'm using:

**Client:** Debian GNU/Linux 8.2 (jessie) with Kernel 3.16.0-4-amd64 OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5, OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015

**Server:** CentOS release 6.6 (Final) with Kernel 2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64 OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

I generate the keys following the step suggest on [Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/SSH#Using_shared_keys) and [CentOS](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/SecuringSSH#head-9c5717fe7f9bb26332c9d67571200f8c1e4324bc) webpages.

But when I try to connect to server using **ssh -p ## user@server**, ssh prompted to enter password still.

I want aclare that when I enter the password I can log in to server, but I want to log in without password.

Anyone have an idea how can solve this issues?

**Client**

```
ssh -vvv
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
           [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]
           [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-Q cipher | cipher-auth | mac | kex | key]
           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] [user@]hostname [command]
```

**Server**

```
ssh -vvv
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile]
           [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path]
           [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
           [user@]hostname [command]
```

**Client**

```
ls -l .ssh/

total 12
-rw------- 1 client client 1766 nov  8 12:51 id_rsa_zeus
-rw-r--r-- 1 client client  395 nov  8 12:51 id_rsa_zeus.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 client client 3493 ago 19 15:56 known_hosts

ls -Z .ssh/

? id_rsa_zeus  ? id_rsa_zeus.pub  ? known_hosts
```

**Server**

```
ls -l .ssh/

total 4
-rw------- 1 server user 395 nov  8 12:21 authorized_keys

ls -Z .ssh/

-rw------- server user ?                                authorized_keys
```

Comment: Please add the output of `ssh -vvv` to your question.

Comment: Also add listings of the `.ssh` dirs (`ls -l` and `ls -Z`) on both client and server please.

Comment: The output of ssh -vvv doesn't really help us.  What @Bram meant was to add -vvv to the SSH commands that you're using.  e.g., "ssh -vvv -p ## user@server".  (You do not need to run this on the server.)

Comment: a common pitfall is that .ssh dir must be own by user ( server user in yoyr cas) , and be drwx------ (that is `chmod 700 .ssh` )

Comment: It has the property permission, like explain and CentOS and Debian webpages... ls -la | grep '.ssh'
drwx------   2 server user  4096 nov  8 12:21 .ssh

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ssh -p 22 -i /full-path-to/privateKeyFileName -l user serverName
```

If that doesn't work, check the SSH authorization log (e.g., /var/log/authlog for OpenSSH, though OpenSSH portable might vary...  try "ls -ltr /var/log/" to identify what log files changed most recently) to see if that provides clues.  If the public key is in the right place on the server (in the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file), the most likely problem is permissions.

Offhand, I'm not sure if -p 0000 is valid.  The default is 22 and you can definitely customize that to other numbers from  1-65535.